# Where on SE can I ask a question about Battlenet?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there a website where I could ask a question, without it being closed, about [Battlenet](http://us.battle.net/en/), Blizzard's website that manages the accounts of games? I have a problem with the site's security feature that does not allow me to play as often as I want to.

I posted the [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/100195/is-there-any-way-for-battlenet-not-to-lock-your-account-while-traveling) on arqade as suggested I leave the link here so people can review it to possibly see if there is a better SE site for such a question.

Comment: If this is an issue concerning your account, it sounds like you should be asking Blizzard support instead...

Comment: i hope it doesnt come to that (since last time ive talk to them they took forever to respond) Its a security feature to keep me from getting hacked so i dont think they should have a problem with me disabling it. (even if its through a proxy or something that blizz wouldnt know about so they couldnt help me)

Comment: Ill still try asking them and then return here if it fails.

Comment: @Xitcod13 You should remember that there is no guarantee that such a question has to be on topic *somewhere* on SE. You could ask on Arqade chat if someone has run into the same problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Questions about Battle.net are on-topic on [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/), there are already [more than 70 questions about it](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battle.net).

Without knowing the exact question I can't say if your specific question would be a good fit for the site. You should check the FAQ and make sure that your question is constructive. If it is a problem specific to your account, probably only Blizzard can help you. If it is a general security feature of Battle.net, asking on Arqade could be successful.

Comment: alright ill post the question there. I posted exactly what the question was about but it was edited out by josh caswell. He also made my question much cleaner though so i aint mad. Ill accept your answer soon.